# Unable to understand the reason for "IndexError: tuple index out of range" while running fit_generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have built a custom model and now wants to it on google colab with dataset from my google drive(dataset belongs to Google Landmark Recognition Challenge in kaggle).
Im using ImageDataGenerator(flow_from_directory) and FitGenerator.

When running the fit_generator, it fails on the last step of the first epoch (before the validation).

I minimized the dataset and the model to shorten the running time as much as possible, and checked if the data is not in the right shape, but it seems right

It's actually the first model I have ever built and Im kinda new in the ML world, so i think i just miss something here..

Here's my code (without some unnecessary parts)

```
                              rotation_range=0,
                              width_shift_range=0,
                               height_shift_range=0,
                               shear_range=0,
                               zoom_range=[0.8, 1.25],
                               horizontal_flip=True,
                               vertical_flip=False,
                               fill_mode='reflect',
                               data_format='channels_last',
                               brightness_range=[0.5, 1.5]) 

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                               rotation_range=30,
                               width_shift_range=0.1,
                               height_shift_range=0.1,
                               shear_range=0.01,
                               zoom_range=[0.8, 1.25],
                               horizontal_flip=True,
                               vertical_flip=False,
                               fill_mode='reflect',
                               data_format='channels_last',
                               brightness_range=[0.5, 1.5])

image_size = (128,128)
batch_size = 20

train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAINING_DATA_DIR,
                                                 target_size=image_size,
                                                 color_mode='rgb',
                                                 batch_size=batch_size,
                                               class_mode='categorical',
                                                 shuffle=True)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                                        VALIDATION_DATA_DIR,
                                         target_size=image_size,
                                         color_mode='rgb',
                                        class_mode = "categorical")

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape = (image_size[0], image_size[1], 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(150))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9), metrics=["accuracy"])

// Calculate the steps sizes
step_size_train = train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
step_size_validation = validation_generator.n//validation_generator.batch_size

// We define an early stopper to avoid wasting compute resources and time
early = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0, patience=2, verbose=1, mode='auto')
networkfileName = RESULTS_PATH + "/" + MODEL_NAME + "{}" + MODEL_ENDING.format(int(time.time()))          
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(networkfileName, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1,save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)

history = model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                   steps_per_epoch=step_size_train,
                   validation_data = validation_generator,
                   validation_steps = step_size_validation,
                   epochs=5,
                   callbacks = [checkpoint, early],
                   workers=1,
                   use_multiprocessing=False,
                   verbose=1)
```

Sadly I dont have enought reputations so I cant add a screenshot, so here's the link : [Exception screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcyUP.png)

Also added the exception output here :

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-db9c44988a08> in <module>()
      7                    workers=1,
      8                    use_multiprocessing=False,
----> 9                    verbose=1)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   2175         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   2176         shuffle=shuffle,
-> 2177         initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   2178 
   2179   def evaluate_generator(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
    214           break
    215 
--> 216       callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
    217       epoch += 1
    218       if callbacks.model.stop_training:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
    212     logs = logs or {}
    213     for callback in self.callbacks:
--> 214       callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
    215 
    216   def on_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
    572     if self.epochs_since_last_save >= self.period:
    573       self.epochs_since_last_save = 0
--> 574       filepath = self.filepath.format(epoch=epoch + 1, **logs)
    575       if self.save_best_only:
    576         current = logs.get(self.monitor)

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Thanks you!

Comment: Did you look into https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6104 ?

Comment: The problem seems to be with the model checkpoint callback. Not really enough info to say more

Comment: @Karl Thanks! Removing the checkpoint callback did fix the issue, but do you have any idea why? I would be happy to use this callback..